# IPv6 fe80:: (link-local) addresses not being assigned to newly created network interfaces in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, ip-address

When I try to add a bridge, it become in UP state without a fe80:: IPv6 address:

```
$ ip link add br0 type bridge
$ ip link set br0 up
$ ip address show br0
40: br0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c2:c3:09:08:da:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

But when I try to do the same, but inside a network namespace the fe80:: address is assigned normally:

```
$ ip netns add nsx
$ ip netns exec nsx ip link add br0 type bridge
$ ip netns exec nsx ip link set br0 up
$ ip netns exec nsx ip address show br0
2: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:45:d1:77:37:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a845:d1ff:fe77:37b3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I also tested in a virtual machine and it has the same problem.

How can I make the newly created interfaces (bridge or tap) to have a fe80:: address when bringing them up?

PS: I'm using NetworkManager, both in host and the virtual machine and my kernel flag net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf is 1.

Comment: 40: br0: <NO-CARRIER> ... state DOWN
  https://serverfault.com/a/1075277/149509

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1594751/rhel7-not-assigning-link-local-ipv6-address-to-a-new-network-interface/1608778#1608778

Comment: If you are using NetworkManager then it automatically enables IPv6 addresses if there are advertisements for them in the network. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IPv6#Stateless_autoconfiguration_(SLAAC)

Comment: Your br0 in default namespace is not UP as you wrote

Comment: Starting a (5.19) Linux system in single user mode and init=/bin/bash makes the host's behavior as usual (ie: UNKNOWN until attached to or the MAC address fixed). So it's something done in host's configuration that makes the host behavior to change. Anyway the behavior with DOWN is a sane behavior.

Comment: @A.B Yeah, indeed, I have been had this problem after compiling and upgrading my Kernel, in the past I always was seeing the fe80:: in any interface. Thanks for clarification and sorry for the crossposts, I thought it was allowed.

Comment: @A.B I tested in Debian testing with kernel 5.19.11 and Fedora 36 with kernel 5.17.5, these two presents the same behavior, now I'm sure this is happening because of newer kernels.

Comment: @phantomcraft and I tested with 5.9.11 booted with init=/bin/bash (ie single user without even systemd) and using immediately ip link add ... type bridge: gets UNKNOWN. Booted normally: DOWN. Not so sure.

Comment: @A.B Today I booted 5.19.11 with init=/bin/bash enabled, the fe80:: appeared in the bridge/tap, I believe it's some app invoked by systemd which causes fe80:: to disappear.

Comment: @phantomcraft behavior difference can be explained in this Q/A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719379/how-to-make-linux-generate-different-mac-addresses-for-different-bridge-devices that's not because of newer kernels, but of newer systemd (-udev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ip` reports `state DOWN` for any interface (you can see a **NO-CARRIER** among the flags), the kernel won't assign a link-local IPv6 address, because the interface hasn't been completely activated. You are going to notice this behavior with any interface that doesn't have a peer connected (a bridge can essentially be considered as a local interface to the host it is created on, and if no ports are attached, that can be taken as a missing connection).

Now, if you are attaching a cable to a physical interface and turn the remote side on or attach a port to a bridge, that essentially means that you are establishing an active link (`ip` is goin to report `state UP`). In this moment the kernel automatically assigns a link-local address to the interface.

If you need to force an IP address even on an interface that is down, you can first assign a value of 1 to `net.ipv6.conf.<interface>.addr_gen_mode`, then reset it to 0. This forces the kernel to assign an IPv6 link-local address to it without having to plug anything in (please note the *tentative* flag set for this link-local address, though, as there haven't been any DAD checks so far so it cannot be used).